# GNOME keyring manager and gnupg

Tags: gnome, gnome3, pgp

I get this

```
gpg: WARNING: The GNOME keyring manager hijacked the GnuPG agent.
gpg: WARNING: GnuPG will not work proberly - please configure that tool to not interfere with the GnuPG system!
```

when I use gnupg-agent with mutt. But the warning doesn't give me clue how to resolve the issue, nor could I find the info from GNOME documentation.

Comment: I noticed the same thing yesterday. I think this was introduced in a recent update, because I have never seen this message before and I have been using Mutt with GPG for years. I hope there is a solution or at least a workaround.
Signing and encrypting mail still works though, despite the error.

Comment: Apparently gpg checks specificly for [GKR](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commit;h=ffa39be5ebfc1059a737905ee317c9b6f3d2a77e). I don't know if it was the reason is or what does 33554509 refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a clash between gpg2 and gnome-keyring and the message is misleading and harmless. If you like to remove the message, execute the following command on a terminal.

```
sed -i s/AGENT_ID/AGENX_ID/ `which gpg2`
```

[More Details can be found here](http://gebner.org/how-to-get-rid-of-the-the-gnome-keyring-manager-hijacked-the-gnupg-agent-warning.html)